# Add namespace to PSR-4-Section in composer.json file from command line interface

Tags: json, bash, laravel, command, composer-php

I'm looking for a way adding namespaces to the autoload PSR-4-Section in the composer.json file of my Laravel project, from the command line interface.

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "App\\": "app/",
      "Modules\\": "modules/",
      /* add more here */
    }
  }
}
```

I was hoping there is a command like `composer require`, but I've not found a working command for this opportunity.

Did anyone come up with a proper solution for this?

Even a script for `bash`, `powershell`, `php`, ... would be appreciated. Being able to run it from the command line is the main thing.

Comment: Why would you need a command for that? How often are you going to add new namespaces?

Comment: To automatically deploy a setup for a developers environment.

Comment: We will not write a script for you, but a simple and effective way would be using PHPs `json_decode()` to convert the composer.json contents to an array, add the namespace definition, and `json_encode()` to convert the adjusted array to json again. This script simply be made executable by using `php script.php`, in your command line.

Answer (score 5):

If someone needs this,
I came up with this approach, which is working for me.

```
public function handle($key, $namespace, $output = 'composer.json')
{
    $file = 'composer.json';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $data["autoload"]["psr-4"][] = array($key => $namespace);
    file_put_contents($output, json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

Comment: JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT is most important piece of this code